# Building OpenCV from source for Android on Ubuntu

Tags: android, opencv, ubuntu, sdk, cmake

I was following instructions from the below link to build openCV on Ubuntu.
https://github.com/chili-epfl/chilitags/blob/master/README-ANDROID.md
But when I try to configure in ccmake, I get the following error.

> CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:592 (message):
>       OpenCV requires Android SDK tools revision 14 or newer.  Otherwise tests
>       and samples will not be compiled.

I have android sdk in $HOME/Android/Sdk folder. I also added the Android sdk folder to PATH. But I still get the above error.

Comment: This is not an *error*, this is **warning**. It means that **Android SDK has been found**, but it is *too old*. Which SDK version you have installed?

Comment: OK. My bad. I didn't go through the whole process. I was thinking it is detecting some problems with my system. Thanks.